# Creating usergroup while user registration in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I would like to create new usergroup in joomla with customized registration form(juser plugin of fabrik) and assign user to this group(this part is missed, really don`t know how to add it). 
I have wrote some script which was included in the php plugin of form. but not sure where is a error.
It would be helpful to get some info where is a error.

```
// Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Insert columns.
$columns = array('parentid','lft','rgt','title');
$title = '{user_registration_form___companyid}';
$child_query1 = "SELECT max('id') FROM '#__usergroups'";
$newgroupid = $child_query1+1;
$parent_id = '2';

$db->setQuery($child_query);
$max_rgt = $db->loadResult();

// calculate left and rgt for new entry
$new_lft = $max_rgt;
$new_rgt = $max_rgt + 1;

// update lft and rgt of all entries having lft , rgt greater than max_rgt
$upd1 = "UPDATE '#__usergroups' SET 'lft' = 'lft' + 2 WHERE 'lft' >= " $max_rgt;
$upd2 = "UPDATE '#__usergroups' SET 'rgt' = 'rgt' + 2 WHERE 'rgt' >= " $max_rgt;


 // Insert values.
 $values = array($parent_id, $new_lft, $new_rgt, $title );


 // Prepare the insert query.
 $query
->insert($db->quoteName('usergroups'))
->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
->values(implode(',', $db->quote($values)));

// Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
$db->setQuery($query);

try {
  // Execute the query
  $result = $db->execute();
  //use $db->query() in Joomla2.5
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // catch any database errors.
}
$newid = (int)$db->insertid(); //get new record id
```

Answer (score 0):

in your way of coding , each user having different usergroup. eg. 10 user in your site 10 usergroup will create ? or you already created user group(10 user group ) ,based on some setting you have to assign user to user group.

eg: you have 10 user group , based on list field(subscriper,developer,...) you can add to user group using JUserHelper.

```
JUserHelper::setUserGroups(integer $userId, array $groups) : boolean

JUserHelper::addUserToGroup(integer $userId, integer $groupId) : boolean

JUserHelper::removeUserFromGroup(integer $userId, integer $groupId) : boolean
```

JUserHelper https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JUserHelper.html